# Show that $A =\left(\begin{smallmatrix}41&12\\12&34\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ is symmetric positive definite

Tags: matrices

After that it asks to find a 2 x 2 matrix B such that $A=B^2$

I was thinking to find the eigenvalues. If they are positive then it means the matrix is spd. 
Then try to diagonalize the matrix and find a matrix B that has the square root of the eigenvalues of A as elements of its diagonal.

Am I in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan.  The way you've defined your $B$, it will be the square root of the diagonalized matrix, not the original.  You'll need to transform it back.

Comment: Hint for alternative method: is there any relationship beetween $A$'s eigenvalues and quantities like, for example $\det A$?

Comment: $det(A)$ equals the product of the eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach is to see that $B$ can be symmetric as well, so write $$B =\left(\begin{matrix}x&y\\y&z\end{matrix}\right)\\B^2 =\left(\begin{matrix}x&y\\y&z\end{matrix}\right) ^2=\left(\begin{matrix}41&12\\12&34\end{matrix}\right)\\
x^2+y^2=41,y(x+z)=12,y^2+z^2=34$$
For which [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D41%2Cy%28x%2Bz%29%3D12%2Cy%5E2%2Bz%5E2%3D34) finds a mess

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is correct, but you needs also the eigenvectors of your matrix $A$.

When you diagonalize $A$ you find $A=PDP^{-1}$ where $P$ is a matrix that has as columns the eigenvectors of $A$.
If you find the matrix $C$ such that $C^2=D$ ( as you has suggested) the you have:
$$
B^2=(PCP^{-1})^2=PCP^{-1}PCP^{-1}=PC^2P^{-1}=PDP^{-1}=A
$$
So $B$ is the square root of $A$.

Comment: Thank you Emilio. I have a further question: For the same matrix $A$ we want to find an upper triangular matrix $U$ such that $A=U^TU$. How do we go about it?

Comment: You can find $U=\begin{bmatrix}x&y\\0 & z \end{bmatrix}$ solving the equation $U^TU=A$. It's not difficult. You can post another question if you have truble.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative method: since $A$ is symmetric, it can be diagonalized within $\mathbb {R}^2$. The eigenvalues $\lambda _{1,2}$ satisfy: $$\det A= \lambda _1 \lambda _2,\quad \text {tr}A=\lambda _1 + \lambda _2;$$
Note that $\det A$ and $\text {tr} A$ are stable under conjugation $A\mapsto C^{-1} A C$.

Now if $\det A\leq0$ the matrix obviously can't be positive definite. If $\det A>0$, $\lambda _1 $ and $\lambda _2$ have the same sign, which is the same sign of $\text {tr}A$. So the symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix is positive definite if and only if: $$\det A>0\quad \text{and}\quad\text {tr}A >0.$$

You can also easily solve for $\lambda _1$ and $\lambda _2$, however finding $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ still requires some computation.